# Good training data for text classification by LDA?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, classification, text-classification, document-classification

I'm classifying content based on LDA into generic topics such as Music, Technology, Arts, Science

This is the process i'm using,

9 topics ->  **Music**, **Technology**, **Arts**, **Science** **etc etc**.

9 documents -> **Music.txt**, **Technology.txt**, **Arts.txt**, **Science.txt** etc etc.

I've filled in each document(.txt file) with about 10,000 lines of content of what i think is "pure" categorical content

I then classify a test document, to see how well the classifier is trained

My Question is,

a.) Is this an efficient way to classify text (using the above steps)?

b.) Where should i be looking for "pure" topical content to fill each of these files? Sources which are not too large (text data > 1GB)

classification is only on "generic" topics such as the above

Comment: One classical free source of categorized documents is Reuters-21578 Text Categorization Collection, http://kdd.ics.uci.edu/databases/reuters21578/reuters21578.html . Lots of other free and non-free NLP coropora and tool are referenced here: http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/links/statnlp.html .

Answer (score 1):

a) The method you describe sounds fine, but everything will depend on the implementation of labeled LDA that you're using. One of the best implementations I know is the [Stanford Topic Modeling Toolbox](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.4/). It is not actively developed anymore, but it worked great when I used it.

b) You can look for topical content on [DBPedia](http://www.dbpedia.org/), which has a structured ontology of topics/entities, and links to Wikipedia articles on those topics/entities.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use bag-of-words (bow) for each class you are using. Or vectors where each column is the frequency of important keywords related to the class you want to target.

Regarding the dictionaries you have DBPedia as yves referred or [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu).

Answer (score 0):

a.)The simplest solution is surely the **k-nearest neighbors algorithm (knn)**. In fact, it will classify new texts with categorical content using an **overlap metric**.

You could find ressources here: [https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=knn+text&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=knn%20text&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults)

Answer (score 0):

**Dataset issue**:
If you are dealing with classifying live user feeds, then I guess no single dataset will suffice your requirement.

Because if new movie `X` released, it might not catch by your classification dataset as the training dataset is obsoleted for it now.

For classification I guess to stay updated with latest datasets, use twitter training datasets. Develop dynamic algorithm which update the classifier with latest updated tweet datasets. You could select top 15-20 hash tag for each category of your choice to get most relevant dataset for each category.

**Classifier:**

Most of the classifier uses [bag of words model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model), you can try out various classifiers and see which gives best result. see :

1. http://www.nltk.org/howto/classify.html
2. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html